# On the iterated automorphism groups of the cyclic groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, finite-groups, automorphism-groups, oeis

Let $C_n$ be the cyclic group of order $n$. Its automorphism group $Aut(C_n)$ is a group of order $\varphi(n)$ isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ the [multiplicative group of integer modulo $n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n). This last group is abelian but not always cyclic, the first non-cyclic being $Aut(C_8) \simeq C_2 \times C_2$. Moreover the iterated automorphism groups $Aut^m(C_n)$ are not always abelian, as $Aut^2(C_8) \simeq S_3$.

By watching the table [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n#Examples_2) for the group structure of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$, we cannot expect an easy classification for the set of groups $Aut(C_n)$, but (**Q1**) what about the following set? $$\{Aut^m(C_n) \ | \ n \ge 1, m \ge 0 \}$$

If it is also non-easy, (**Q2**) what about the set of groups $Aut^m(C_n)$ which are isomorphic to $Aut^{m+1}(C_n)$? For $n \le 15$, it is exactly $\{C_1,S_3,D_8  \}$ as shown by the following table:

$$\scriptsize{ \begin{array}{c|c}
G  &C_1&C_2&C_3&C_4&C_5&C_6&C_7&C_8&C_9&C_{10}&C_{11}&C_{12}&C_{13}&C_{14}&C_{15} \newline 
                             \hline
Aut(G) &-&C_1&C_2&C_2&C_4&C_2&C_6&C_2^2&C_6&C_4&C_{10}&C_2^2&C_{12}&C_6&C_2 \times C_4  \newline
                             \hline
Aut^2(G) &-&-&C_1&C_1&C_2&C_1&C_2&S_3&C_2&C_2&C_4&S_3&C_2^2&C_2&D_8 \newline
                              \hline
Aut^3(G) &-&-&-&-&C_1&-&C_1&-&C_1&C_1&C_2&-&S_3&C_1&- \newline
                               \hline
Aut^4(G) &- &- &-&-&-&-&-&-&-&-&C_1&-&-&-&-
\end{array} }$$

Let $\alpha(n)$ be the smallest $m \ge 0$ such that $Aut^m(C_n) \simeq Aut^{m+1}(C_n)$. Then:

$$\scriptsize{ \begin{array}{c|c}
n  &1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15 \newline 
                             \hline
\alpha(n) &0&1&2&2&3&2&3&2&3&3&4&2&2&3&2 
\end{array} }$$

Surprisingly, for $n<15$ (but not for $n=15$), $\alpha(n)$ is exactly the number of iterations of the [Carmichael lambda function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) $\lambda$ needed to reach $1$ from $n$ (OEIS [A185816](https://oeis.org/A185816)). (**Q3**) Why?

A specific OEIS sequence has just been created ([A331921](https://oeis.org/A331921)) providing the value of $\alpha(n)$ for $n<32$; in this case, $\alpha(n) \le 5$ and $\{\mathrm{Aut}^5(C_n) \ | \ n < 32 \} = \{C_1,S_3,D_8,D_{12},\mathrm{PGL}(2,7) \}$. A usual laptop cannot compute $\alpha(n)$ for $n \ge 32$ (you are welcome to contribute to this sequence), we just know that $\alpha(32) \ge 8$. Here is the sequence $|Aut^n(C_{32})|$ for $n \le 8$:
$$\scriptsize{ \begin{array}{c|c}
n  &0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8 \newline 
                             \hline
|Aut^n(C_{32})| & 2^5&2^4&2^4&2^6&2^{7}3&2^{9}3&2^{11}3&2^{16}3&2^{41}3^3 5^1 7 \newline 
                             \hline
\text{IdGroup}(Aut^n(C_{32})) & [32,1]&[16,5]&[16,11]&[64,138]&[384,17948]&[1536,?]&[6144,?]&?&?
\end{array} }$$

We can also consider the sequence of $n$ such that $\exists m \ge 0$ with $Aut^m(C_n) \simeq C_1$:
$1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 14, 18, 19, 22, 23, 27, 38, 46, 47, 54, 81,  \dots$ ([A117729](https://oeis.org/A117729)).
It seems to be a (strict) subsequence of [A179401](https://oeis.org/A179401), so (**Q4**) why $Aut^m(C_n) \simeq C_1$ $\Rightarrow$ $\varphi^2(n) = \lambda^2(n)$?

It is an open problem whether the sequence $Aut^n(G)$ stabilizes (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/5635/34538)). For a given finite group $G$ there are three possibilities:

- (1):  $\exists m  \ge 0 $ such that $Aut^{m+1}(G) \simeq Aut^{m}(G)$,
- (2):  not (1) and  $\exists m \ge 0$ such that $\exists r>0$ with $Aut^{m+r}(G) \simeq Aut^{m}(G)$,
- (3): not (1) and not (2), i.e.,  $\forall m \ge 0$ and $\forall r>0$ then $Aut^{m+r}(G) \not \simeq Aut^{m}(G)$.

The case (1) means that the sequence $(Aut^m(G))_m$ is constant for $m$ large enough, (2) means that it is periodic non-constant for $m$ large enough, and (3) means never periodic. The existence of finite groups in cases (2) or (3) is open. (**Q5**) Can we rule out the cases (2) and (3) for the cyclic groups?

If not, let redefine $\alpha(n)$ as the smallest $m \ge 0$ such that $\exists r>0$ with $Aut^{m}(C_n) \simeq Aut^{m+r}(C_n)$ if $C_n$ is in cases (1) or (2), and $\infty$ in the case (3).

Comment: In your table for $C_{32}$ you can add that the last two automorphism groups have orders $2^{16}\cdot 3$ and $2^{41}\cdot 3^3\cdot 5\cdot 7$.

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki: Nice, how did you compute them? Did you identify the group structures? Can you go beyond?

Comment: It is crucial to convert the automorphism group to a more efficient structure like PcGroup (for solvable groups) or PermutationGroup, at each iteration (can be done in GAP or MAGMA). Beyond that, I run out of memory.

Answer (score 6):

It seems to me that the structure of ${\rm Aut}^{m}(C_{n})$ also depends heavily on the prime factorization of $n$, and I don't really see any reason to expect the answer to Q1 to be any more tractable than determining the structure of ${\rm Aut}(C_{n})$.

For example (just to illustrate) , if we choose a prime $p$, greater than $3$, and then we take a pair of primes $q_{1}$ and $q_{2}$ so that each $q_{i}-1$ is divisible by $p$, but not by $p^{2}$, and we set $n = q_{1}q_{2}$, then ${\rm Aut}^{2}(C_{n})$ has a direct factor isomorphic to 
${\rm GL}(2,p)$, and is not solvable. Furthermore the involvement of ${\rm PSL}(2,p)$ in ${\rm Aut}^{m}(C_{n})$ persists for $m >2$.

Comment: I just tried some computations with $n=11 \times 31$, and the orders of the series of automorphism groups seem to be increasing rapidly, starting $300$, $5760$, $46080$, $566231040$.

Comment: Q1 asks for a classification of the set $\{Aut^m(C_n) \ | \ n>0,m \ge 0  \}$ (up to equivalence). This set could be easy to describe "negatively", in the sense that it could be all the finite groups except a tractable list.

Comment: @DerekHolt Is it known whether, for a given finite group $G$, $Aut^n(G)$ is constant for $n$ large enough?

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: and what about the existence of a finite group $G$ for which ${\rm Aut}^{n}(G)$ does not stabilize? Any known cyclic group example? Derek's example $C_{341}$ is a candidate, but it is known? Is there a finite group $G$ whose sequence ${\rm Aut}^{n}(G)$ is (for $n$ large enough) periodic non-constant?

Comment: There are several related posts on this issue, such as [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151352) and [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5635). But I am not aware of any known example in which the orders of the groups in the  chain of automorphism groups of a finite group have been proved to be unbounded.

Comment: Do you think we can translate Q5 into a purely number theoretic problem?