# Groups with abelian automorphism group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-groups

In a [paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01229715), the authors Jonah-Konvisser say

> Until recently (~1975), there were no published examples of non-abelian groups with abelian automorphism groups. Heinken and Liebeck have methods for constructing such $p$-groups;.....

When I saw the paper of [Heinken and Liebeck](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01238631), I saw that much of their work involves construction of following object: *given a group $K$ with $|K|\geq 5$, construct a $p$-group $G$ of class $2$ and exponent $p^2$ such that $\mathrm{Aut}(G)/\mathrm{Aut}_\mathrm{c}(G)$ is isomorphic to $K$.*  [Here $\mathrm{Aut}_\mathrm{c}(G)$ is the set of those automorphisms of $G$ which are identity on $G/Z(G)$.]

So, I didn't find the place in which they construct groups with abelian automorphism group; this confused me with quoted statement from paper of Jonah-Konvisser.

**Question:** Can one indicate me where, Heinken and Liebeck do construction of non-abelian $p$-groups with abelian automorphism group?

Comment: Some more details are given [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9944/when-is-autg-abelian). Instead of Heinken and Liebeck one could use the reference G.A. Miller.

Comment: @Burde: I am sorry. I have seen example of Miller and some generalization of it done by some people. I wanted to see the example(s) of Heinken and Liebeck;  but I didn't find it explicitly in their paper, hence posted above question.

Answer (score 1):

With the hope that it may help somebody, I indicate that the groups $G$ with $K = 1$, the trivial group, provide the desired examples. One such graph is given in the paper itself. For more details and progress on the problem, one may look a recent survey at https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.00615, which is now published(https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-981-13-2047-7_7).

Comment: The questioner starts:  "Given $K$ with $\lvert K\rvert \ge 5$ …".  How does this fit with $K = 1$?

Comment: @LSpice it fits with $K=1$ because there're no $|K|\ge 5$ assumption in the reference.